# Reset network configuration and set WiFi Static IP

Tags: wifi, connection, dhcp

I follow [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/69844) tutorial to be able to setup static IP address on WiFi connection, in particular, after change `/etc/network/interfaces` file I do this two commands

```
sudo systemctl disable dhcpcd
sudo systemctl enable networking
```

after that I am not be able to connect on WiFi but I am able to connect via wired LAN.

OS is **RASPBIAN JESSIE WITH DESKTOP** version 8 jessie.

On network icon I can see tho errors:

```
eth0: Link is down
wlan0: Not associated
```

and

```
No wireless interfaces found
```

below my `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` file:

```
A sample configuration for dhcpcd.
# See dhcpcd.conf(5) for details.

# Allow users of this group to interact with dhcpcd via the control socket.
#controlgroup wheel

# Inform the DHCP server of our hostname for DDNS.
hostname

# Use the hardware address of the interface for the Client ID.
clientid
# or
# Use the same DUID + IAID as set in DHCPv6 for DHCPv4 ClientID as per RFC4361.
#duid

# Persist interface configuration when dhcpcd exits.
persistent

# Rapid commit support.
# Safe to enable by default because it requires the equivalent option set
# on the server to actually work.
option rapid_commit

# A list of options to request from the DHCP server.
option domain_name_servers, domain_name, domain_search, host_name
option classless_static_routes
# Most distributions have NTP support.
option ntp_servers
# Respect the network MTU.
# Some interface drivers reset when changing the MTU so disabled by default.
#option interface_mtu

# A ServerID is required by RFC2131.
require dhcp_server_identifier

# Generate Stable Private IPv6 Addresses instead of hardware based ones
slaac private

# A hook script is provided to lookup the hostname if not set by the DHCP
# server, but it should not be run by default.
nohook lookup-hostname
```

I change also `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Of course I reset `hdcpcd` on running these commands:

```
sudo systemctl disable networking
sudo systemctl enable dhcpcd
```

But the status is as described before: cunenction with DHCP on wired and no connection with WiFi.

I want to reset all and after set Static IP address on WiFi connection

If I run `systemctl status dhcpcd.service` when connected to wired network:

```
dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since gio 2017-07-06 18:08:17 CEST; 16h ago
 Main PID: 645 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─645 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w
```

If I do it when I am without LAN cable and restart:

```
dhcpcd.service - dhcpcd on all interfaces
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service; enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/dhcpcd.service.d
           └─wait.conf
   Active: active (running) since ven 2017-07-07 10:55:27 CEST; 53s ago
  Process: 382 ExecStart=/sbin/dhcpcd -q -w (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 645 (dhcpcd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dhcpcd.service
           └─645 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -w
Warning: Unit file changed on disk, 'systemctl daemon-reload' recommended.
```

With another installation of the same OS, I have the second result but here WiFi works.

Comment: I see no attempt to set static IP addresses. You have to **EITHER** use `dhcpcd` **OR** Debian networking. If you use the latter the GUI Network icon will not work (as it relies on `dhcpcd`). I still fail to understand **WHY**

Comment: Yep, I try to setup static IP with debian networking, but when I see the error in icon and no connection, I try to reset all things back, now with this configuratin WiFi doesn't working anymore.

Comment: What does `systemctl status dhcpcd.service` show? **DO NOT** post into Comments, edit your question.

Comment: Ok perfect, I can see some differences with cable and without